# Exception handling with FOR LOOP and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, plsql

My task is to print the total number of columns of my table. Then for a specific ID, print only those columns' name that has value ( if a column contains null for that specific ID then skip it). I am using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in my code inside a FOR LOOP. If `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` found no data in a column then it throws no_data_exception which I can handle, but I just can't continue my loop after that exception.

```
DECLARE
    COL_TOTAL_NUM NUMBER;
    COL_NAME VARCHAR2(500);
    COL_VAL VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COL_TOTAL_NUM FROM user_tab_cols WHERE TABLE_NAME='PAY_SLIP_FEB_16';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL COLUMN NUMBER = '||COL_TOTAL_NUM);
    FOR A IN 1..COL_TOTAL_NUM LOOP
      SAVEPOINT S1;
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO COL_NAME FROM user_tab_cols WHERE TABLE_NAME='PAY_SLIP_FEB_16'
                                                  AND COLUMN_ID=A;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||COL_NAME||' FROM PAY_SLIP_FEB_16 WHERE EMP_ID=''FMINF83057'' AND '||COL_NAME||' IS NOT NULL' INTO COL_NAME;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COL_NAME||' -> '||COL_VAL);
    END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
        ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT S1;
END;
```

My output is :

```
TOTAL COLUMN NUMBER = 117
EMP_ID -> FMINF83057
MONTH -> 2
YEAR -> 2016
NAME ->   Mr.Md.Mohiduzzaman
DESIGNATION -> Professor
DEPARTMENT -> Institute of Nutrition and Food Sciences
GRADE -> 2
BASIC_PAY -> 73720
HOUSE_RENT_ALLOWANCE -> 19750
MEDICAL_ALLOWANCE -> 700
ERROR
```

The for loop stops here. How do I continue it after that error?

Comment: So you want to print `ERROR` and then you want FOR LOOP to continue? If that is the case, you can do that but the loop will start from the beginning as you have `ROLLBACK` command.

Comment: I dont need to print error. I printed it to make sure I can handle the exception. I just need to skip it and continue the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [CONTINUE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/continue-statement-in-11gr1) statement when you encounter the error. It is available from Oracle 11g onwards. But you need to do that *inside* the loop. I moved your exception part inside the loop,  and enclosed it within a block:

```
DECLARE
    COL_TOTAL_NUM NUMBER;
    COL_NAME VARCHAR2(500);
    COL_VAL VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COL_TOTAL_NUM FROM user_tab_cols WHERE TABLE_NAME='PAY_SLIP_FEB_16';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL COLUMN NUMBER = '||COL_TOTAL_NUM);
    FOR A IN 1..COL_TOTAL_NUM LOOP
    BEGIN
      SAVEPOINT S1;
      SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO COL_NAME FROM user_tab_cols WHERE TABLE_NAME='PAY_SLIP_FEB_16'
                                              AND COLUMN_ID=A;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||COL_NAME||' FROM PAY_SLIP_FEB_16 WHERE EMP_ID=''FMINF83057'' AND '||COL_NAME||' IS NOT NULL' INTO COL_NAME;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COL_NAME||' -> '||COL_VAL);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');
        CONTINUE;                         --move to the next iteration of the loop
    END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The statement tells the compiler to skip the current iteration of the loop and jump to the following one. It is particularly useful for logging purposes.

Comment: I could not use the exception inside the for loop because I did not enclose it within a block, but after enclosing the loop now I can use it, thanks a lot.